# Retrieving a specific range of data from an array (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, instruments, midi

I want to populate a `ComboBox` with the default 128 MIDI instruments, but calling `Synthesizer.getDefaultSoundbank().getInstruments()` returns a list of **every** instrument available (more than 400 on my machine).

I then copy the list of all the available instruments into an `Object` array (named `_instruments`), although it gives me everything I could ever need, I **only need the first 128 elements**.

```
            _soundbank = _synthesizer.getDefaultSoundbank();
            _synthesizer.loadAllInstruments(_soundbank);
            _synthesizer.close();   
            _instrument = _soundbank.getInstruments();
```

Is there a specific way to get the first set of instruments or would it be possible to simply trim anything after the first 128 elements in an array? That way I would only be left with the first full set.

I hope that makes sense, it's an awkward scenario. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The shortest and more comfortable way to do it would be using `Arrays.copyOf`. See below:

```
_instrument = Arrays.copyOf(_soundbank.getInstruments(), 128);
```

See the [Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28T%5b%5d,%20int%29) for more info.

Comment: Works like a charm, much better than my initial implementation. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

What about Java's own [Arrays.copyOfRange(..)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange%28T%5b%5d,%20int,%20int%29) to extract the first 128?